# Let $p(z)$ be a polynomial, $\, z \in \mathbb{C}$. Show that if $\left|p(z) \right| \leqslant \left|e^z \right|$ for every $z$, then $p=0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $p(z)$ be a polynomial, $\, z \in \mathbb{C}$. Show that if $\left|p(z) \right| \leqslant \left|e^z \right|$ for every $z$, then $p=0$.

I proved that if $f$ is entire and $\left|f(z) \right| \leqslant \left|e^z \right|$ for every $z \in \mathbb{C}$, then $f(z)=ce^z$ for some $c \in \mathbb{C}$. Since complex polynomials are entire, could we just conclude that $c=0$ in this case, since $ce^z$ is not a polynomial for any $c \ne 0$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: My ability to read the minds of problem authors says that it might not be the _intended_ solution, but there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Arthur You might be right, the textbook gives a hint: "Look at $z=x<0$"

Comment: That's the hint I would've given too, had I written this problem. Still, as long as the problem doesn't _specifically_ state that you must use the hint, your solution is a good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is fine, as said several times in the comments. Here is an *intended* solution, using the hint, for completeness (and to get this question off the "unanswered" queue):

Let $p$ be a polynomial of degree $n \geq 1$, and set
$$
p(z) = a_nz^n + a_{n-1}z^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1z + a_0
$$
Then there is an $r>0$ be such that $|a_nz^n| > |a_{n-1}z^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1z + a_0| + 3$ for all $|z|\geq r$ (in other words, if you're far enough from the origin, the $n$-th degree term dominates the rest of $p$, with some margin). Now look at $|p(-r)|$. By the above inequality, interpreted as a triangle inequality, it is at least $3$. But $|p(z)| < |e^z|$ implies that $|p(-r)| < e^{-r} < e < 3$, which is a contradiction.

Therefore $p$ is constant, and again, by looking as negative reals, it's not hard to see that this constant must be $0$.